# Why does creating a video element dynamically using jQuery not work in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html

I am trying to recreate the following with Jquery

```
<video width="640" height="264" autoplay>
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4bkpU/2/

I have come up with the following but in IE9 the video element is empty, can anyone tell me why and what I would need to change to be able to dynamically add videos in IE9? It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

HTML

```
<div id="videoHolder">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var video = $('<video width="640" height="264" autoplay></video>')
            .append('<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />')
            .append('<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm" />')
            .append('<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg" />')
            .appendTo($("#videoHolder"));
```

UPDATED - closed the video tag above and addded new link

http://jsfiddle.net/8Cevq/

Comment: Try with `$('<video width="640" height="264" autoplay></video>')` (add `</video>` closing tag)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following, this works:

```
$("#videoHolder").html(
    '<video width="640" height="264" autoplay>' +
        '<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
        '<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm"></source>' +
        '<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg"></source>' +
    '</video>');
```

[JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/4bkpU/15/).

What I did to get this working was:

- A) use the `html` method to inject the desired mark-up all at once
- B) Altered tags (on both `video` and `source`) to use full closing tags as opposed to shorthand `/>`

<sub>A rather cool video, by the way.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou very much. Seems odd that it neeeds to be done this way?

Comment: No worries. I think this way is a little more clear, anyway; using `append` on a bunch of strings then `appendTo` for the significant element could come across a little too elaborate at first glance.

Comment: @Tom - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878367/video-tag-not-working-in-ie-9 for the explanation why you have to insert the video tag all at once using $(element).html(videoElement).  In short, there is a bug in IE9 that does not allow adding source tags after a video tag is added, they must be added at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

IE9 doesn't like it when you add the `<video>` element's contents dynamically, so you must add the `<video>` element and it's contents all at once.

Note: IE9 doesn't seem to have a problem with the shorthand `<source ... />` as long as you don't try to add it afterwards.

Comment: This seems really similar to what's happening to me right now. Is there any more details on what it doesn't like?