# jQuery Appends not appearing in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, html5-video, jquery-backstretch

I'm modifying a background image stretching script called backstretch (found [here](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)) to stretch an HTML5 Video as a full screen background in the browser.

I have this working with the following code in Chrome, Safari and FireFox, however, in IE9 (surprise, surprise) it's not appending these appends to the video element for the different sources.

```
$('video').append("<source src='"+src+".webm' type='video/webm' />");
$('video').append("<source src='"+src+".ogv' type='video/ogg' />");
$('video').append("<source src='"+src+".mp4' type='video/mp4' />");
```

Here is the whole script in it's entirety.  Any thoughts or help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
/*
 * jQuery Backstretch
 * Version 1.2.8
 * http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/
 *
 * Add a dynamically-resized background image to the page
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Scott Robbin (srobbin.com)
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 * https://raw.github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/master/LICENSE.txt
 *
*/

;(function($) {

$.backstretchvideo = function(src, options, callback) {
    var defaultSettings = {
        centeredX: true         // Should we center the image on the X axis?
      , centeredY: true         // Should we center the image on the Y axis?
      , speed: 0                // fadeIn speed for background after image loads (e.g. "fast" or 500)
    }
  , $container = $("#backstretch")
  , settings = $container.data("settings") || defaultSettings // If this has been called once before, use the old settings as the default
  , existingSettings = $container.data('settings')
  , rootElement, supportsFixedPosition, useWindowInnerHeight
  , imgRatio, bgImg, bgWidth, bgHeight, bgOffset, bgCSS;

    // Extend the settings with those the user has provided
    if(options && typeof options == "object") $.extend(settings, options);

    // Just in case the user passed in a function without options
    if(options && typeof options == "function") callback = options;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Taken from jQuery Mobile 1.1.0
         *  http://jquerymobile.com/
         *
         *  In a nutshell, we need to figure out if fixed positioning is supported.
         *  Unfortunately, this is very difficult to do on iOS, and usually involves
         *  injecting content, scrolling the page, etc.. It's ugly.
         *  jQuery Mobile uses this workaround. It's not ideal, but works.
         *
         *  Modified to detect IE6
         */
        var w = window
          , ua = navigator.userAgent
          , platform = navigator.platform
            // Rendering engine is Webkit, and capture major version
          , wkmatch = ua.match( /AppleWebKit\/([0-9]+)/ )
          , wkversion = !!wkmatch && wkmatch[ 1 ]
          , ffmatch = ua.match( /Fennec\/([0-9]+)/ )
          , ffversion = !!ffmatch && ffmatch[ 1 ]
          , operammobilematch = ua.match( /Opera Mobi\/([0-9]+)/ )
          , omversion = !!operammobilematch && operammobilematch[ 1 ]
          , iematch = ua.match( /MSIE ([0-9]+)/ )
          , ieversion = !!iematch && iematch[ 1 ];

        supportsFixedPosition = !(
          // iOS 4.3 and older : Platform is iPhone/Pad/Touch and Webkit version is less than 534 (ios5)
          (( platform.indexOf( "iPhone" ) > -1 || platform.indexOf( "iPad" ) > -1  || platform.indexOf( "iPod" ) > -1 ) && wkversion && wkversion < 534 )
          ||
          // Opera Mini
          ( w.operamini && ({}).toString.call( w.operamini ) === "[object OperaMini]" )
          ||
          ( operammobilematch && omversion < 7458 )
          ||
          //Android lte 2.1: Platform is Android and Webkit version is less than 533 (Android 2.2)
          ( ua.indexOf( "Android" ) > -1 && wkversion && wkversion < 533 )
          ||
          // Firefox Mobile before 6.0 -
          ( ffversion && ffversion < 6 )
          ||
          // WebOS less than 3
          ( "palmGetResource" in window && wkversion && wkversion < 534 )
          ||
          // MeeGo
          ( ua.indexOf( "MeeGo" ) > -1 && ua.indexOf( "NokiaBrowser/8.5.0" ) > -1 )
          ||
          // IE6
          ( ieversion && ieversion <= 6)
        );

        // Set the root element
        rootElement = supportsFixedPosition ? $(window) : $(document);

        // Should we use the window's innerHeight?
        useWindowInnerHeight = supportsFixedPosition && window.innerHeight;

        // Initialize the plugin
        _init();
    });

    // For chaining
    return this;

    function _init() {
        // Prepend image, wrapped in a DIV, with some positioning and zIndex voodoo
        if(src) {
            var img;

            // If this is the first time that backstretch is being called
            if($container.length == 0) {
                $container = $("<div />").attr("id", "backstretch")
                                         .css({left: 0, top: 0, position: supportsFixedPosition ? "fixed" : "absolute", overflow: "hidden", zIndex: -999999, margin: 0, padding: 0, height: "100%", width: "100%"});
            } else {
                // Prepare to delete any old images
                $container.find("video").addClass("deleteable");
            }

            /* img = $("<img />").css({position: "absolute", display: "none", margin: 0, padding: 0, border: "none", zIndex: -999999, maxWidth: "none"})
                              .bind("load", function(e) { */

            //Video Background
            src = src.substring(0, src.length - 4)                
            img = $('<video poster="'+src+'_poster.jpg" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="backstrech_video_background" />')
            // Moved CSS to Stylesheet
            //.css({position: "relative", display: "none", margin: 0, padding: 0, border: "none", zIndex: -999999, maxWidth: "none"})
                              .bind("play", function(e) {

                                  var $self = $(this),
                                      imgWidth, imgHeight;

                                  $self.css({width: "inherit", height: "auto"});
                                  imgWidth = this.width || $(e.target).width();
                                  imgHeight = this.height || $(e.target).height();
                                  imgRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight;

                                  _adjustBG();
                                  $self.fadeIn(settings.speed, function(){
                                      // Remove the old images, if necessary.
                                      $container.find('.deleteable').remove();
                                      // Callback
                                      if(typeof callback == "function") callback();
                                  });
                              })
                              .appendTo($container);

            // Append the container to the body, if it's not already there
            if($("body #backstretch").length == 0) {
                /*
                 * Scroll the page one pixel to get the right window height on iOS
                 * Pretty harmless for everyone else
                */
                if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0 ) window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                $("body").append($container);
            }

            // Attach the settings
            $container.data("settings", settings);

            //video.attr("src", src);  // Hack for IE img onload event

            $('video').append("<source src='"+src+".webm' type='video/webm' />");
            $('video').append("<source src='"+src+".ogv' type='video/ogg' />");
            $('video').append("<source src='"+src+".mp4' type='video/mp4' />");

            // Adjust the background size when the window is resized or orientation has changed (iOS)
            $(window).unbind("resize.backstretch").bind("resize.backstretch", function() {
              // Need to do this in order to get the right window height
              if("onorientationchange" in window) {
                if (window.pageYOffset === 0) window.scrollTo(0, 1);
              }
             _adjustBG()
            });
        }
    }

    function _adjustBG() {
        try {
            bgCSS = {left: 0, top: 0}
          , rootWidth = bgWidth = rootElement.width()
          , rootHeight = useWindowInnerHeight ? window.innerHeight : rootElement.height()
          , bgHeight = bgWidth / imgRatio;

            // Make adjustments based on image ratio
            // Note: Offset code provided by Peter Baker (http://ptrbkr.com/). Thanks, Peter!
            if(bgHeight >= rootHeight) {
                bgOffset = (bgHeight - rootHeight) /2;
                if(settings.centeredY) bgCSS.top = "-" + bgOffset + "px";
            } else {
                bgHeight = rootHeight;
                bgWidth = bgHeight * imgRatio;
                bgOffset = (bgWidth - rootWidth) / 2;
                if(settings.centeredX) bgCSS.left = "-" + bgOffset + "px";
            }

            $container.css({width: rootWidth, height: rootHeight})
                      .find("video").css({width: bgWidth, height: bgHeight}).css(bgCSS);
        } catch(err) {
            // IE7 seems to trigger _adjustBG before the image is loaded.
            // This try/catch block is a hack to let it fail gracefully.
        }
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'va had a similar problem in IE9 also. My solution was to give an absolute path to the source. For some reason, if I wrote for example ../folder/video.mp4 it would not work in IE but when I wrote http://www.mydomain.com/folder/video.mp4, it worked. Worth a try.

Comment: Just to be sure, use IE9 inspection manager to make sure that nothing gets appended. It probably is appended but you just don't see the video

Comment: @ComputerArts Thanks for the responses!  I've tried putting in absolute URLs with no luck.  I've also used IE9's developer tools to look at the code as it's been generated in IE9 and it is nothing has been appended.  I've had the same generated code working in IE9 when a ran a just a static html file with no scripting so I do not know whats going on with it...

Comment: Did you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174790/why-does-creating-a-video-element-dynamically-using-jquery-not-work-in-ie9

Comment: Also found this. Might help. http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. I spent an hour trying to find the root of the problem and I found out that for some strange reason IE will not include a source element. I tried everything else... even when I changed the element name to "sourc", it works.

Probably the only way around this is to append the whole video element with the source tags as one string. In my case (I already had the video el. generated in php), I had to get the starting video tag with

```
var video_html = $( '#sve_video' ).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

I wanted to change only the source tags, and if they were not present, just insert my new tags like this:

```
// get first occurence of '<source'
    var first_src_pos = video_html.indexOf('<source');
    // trim string either before first source, or before closing video tag
    var video_start_tag_end = ( first_src_pos > 0 )
        ? first_src_pos
        : video_html.length - 8;
    var video_start_tag = video_html.substring( 0, video_start_tag_end );
```