# Jquery add html5 video programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have an up-loader that uploads videos and images, these are then displayed back the user. The images display fine but the videos only display the poster and the control buttons. However the video doesn't play.

```
function display_uploads(data){
    var string = '';
    var content = '';
    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++){
        if(data[x].type === 'image'){
            content = '<li>'+
            '<div class="pp_right">&nbsp;</div>'+
            '<div class="msg_text_right"><img src="'+data[x]['file']+'" /></div>'+
            '<div style="clear:both"></div>'+
        '</li>';
        }else{
            var video = data[x]['file'].split('/');
            var src = video[0];
            var vid = video[parseInt(video.length - 1)];
            vid = vid.split('.');
            video = src + '/' + vid[0] + '.' + data[x]['type'];
            content = '<li>'+
            '<div class="pp_right">&nbsp;</div>'+
            '<div class="msg_text_right">'+
            '<video controls="controls" poster="'+data[x]['file']+'">'+
            '<source src="'+ video +'" type="video/'+ data[x]['type'] +'"/>'+
            'You browser does not support videos'+
            '</video></div>'+
            '<div style="clear:both"></div>'+
        '</li>';
        }
        string += content;
        content = '';
    }
    return string;
}
```

Coming from PHP to Jquery I thought `$('#some_div').append(display_images(data));` would be the same as `echo 'my images and videos';`

Is there a a jquery function that initiates the video as a html5 video so I can play it or is this done purely when the browser loads like php?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try this:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = 'yourvideourl';
video.play();
```

Comment: wouldn't that play the video automatically though

Comment: Yes but from this point you can use the video API to change things like this. Just remove the 'video.play()' and add 'video.autoPlay = false'

Answer (score 0):

I belive this will help you.

HTML

JQuery

var video = $('')
            .append('')
            .append('')
            .append('')
            .appendTo($("#videoHolder"));

Anser was taken from
[Why does creating a video element dynamically using jQuery not work in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174790/why-does-creating-a-video-element-dynamically-using-jquery-not-work-in-ie9)

Credit to the responder in the above link.

Comment: same outcome as mine, is .avi a supported file type