# Video autoplay not working on chrome and IE when being appended via jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, video, autoplay

I have a strange issue:
on these two pages I have a video which suppose to auto-play and loop. for some reason the video autoplays on firefox but not on chrome and IE. This seems like a very simple issue, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

http://www.ayzenberg.com/about/what-we-do.html

http://www.ayzenberg.com/about/careers.html

I am appending the video using jQuery .html() function.
Thank you!

Comment: You're adding the `VIDEO` tag after the page has loaded using Javascript. I don't know what the correct behavior for a browser is in this case, but the `VIDEO` tag and the associated `autoplay` attribute is missing during page load. You may have to trigger the video to play after the Javascript adds the tag to the page.

Comment: This is true, it is being appended dynamically.

Comment: what is the right way to append it so it works? I am using jQuery html() function...
after reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174790/why-does-creating-a-video-element-dynamically-using-jquery-not-work-in-ie9 I also tried adding </source> but with no success

Comment: Try `jQuery('#article-hero-vid')[0].play();`

Comment: yes, I did something like that to resolve this document.getElementById('article-hero-vid').play();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to manually play the video to make it work cross-browser:

```
document.getElementById('article-hero-vid').play();
```

Not sure why appending a video with autoplay works only on firefox... but it is!

Answer (score 1):

> > try to put a image  as autoplay poster , instead of keeping autoplay="".

```
<video id="bgvid" autoplay poster ="image/splitmoneyImage.jpg">
```

Comment: one of the videos has a poster image and the other doesn't. I tried adding or removing the poster image, but with not success